# Mongoose/BodyParser not correctly accepting urlencoded POST requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

I've been mostly following these two (suspiciously) similar tutorials to learn back end web development.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4#disqus_thread

http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/05/05/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-crud/

However, when I get to the part where you accept a post request in order to edit the database, I'm running into a problem. I believe I have body-parser set up correctly

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true}));
```

and I believe that I'm correctly handling the request.

```
var itemRouter = router.route('/items');

//Creating an endpoint for POSTS /api/beers
itemRouter.post(function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body); //This always returns {}
    var newItem = new Item();
    newItem.name = req.body.name; //These two lines of code are replaced in the working JSON version
    newItem.quantity = req.body.name; //These two lines of code are replaced in the working JSON version

    //Saves the new item to the database
    newItem.save(function(err){
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        //sends a response

        res.json({
            message: 'Item added to the database!',
            data: newItem
        });
    });
});
```

However, clearly something is going wrong. I'm using postman to send requests to my server with `{Content-Type : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }`, but it isn't correctly getting that information as the console.log I have commented always returns an empty object showing that no information from the body is making it to that point.

I am able to correctly handle JSON formatted inputs by replacing the marked two lines with

```
newItem.name= req.body[0].value;
newItem.quantity = req.body[1].value;
```

However, I would like to figure this issue out and learn from it rather than hack a workaround. I've attached the complete source code at the gist below. Thanks in advance for all the help!

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3a96bb30fd29a5c6852b77acac9963df

This is what I'm getting in my database:

`{"id":"5a9e0d9f5ecb6825b8d68544","_v":0}`

This is what I am hoping to get in my database:

`{"id":"5a9dff951281120fac21aa18","name":"Pepperoni Pizza","quantity":8,"_v":0}`

Comment: can you upload the screenshot of a postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update and restart of postman fixed the issue. I was able to confirm that my original code and process worked on other devices.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set `body-parser` as

```
 // set bodyparser for accepting json value
    app.use(bodyParser.json())

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// then rest code here
```

Comment: Changing Extended to false did not fix the problem. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @JacksonTenor `extended to false` is not problem . did you set `app.use(bodyParser.json())` in your file.

Comment: Yes, app.use(bodyParser.json()) is already in my file. It is already successfully reading JSON formatted files from Postman. I cannot get it to read x-www-form-encoded.